# Expectation of ratio of dependent variables

Tags: expected-value, marginal-distribution, ratio, independence

I am currently studying the behaviour of the expected values of the form
$$
\mathrm{E}_{ij}(Y) = \mathrm{E}\left( \frac{Y_i - Y_j}{Y_1 + \dots + Y_n} \right),
$$
where $Y$ can equal either 0 or 1, marginal probabilities $P(Y_i = 1) = m_i$ are considered given, and $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ are assumed to be dependent. What can be said about $\mathrm{E}_{ij}$ in terms of $m_k, k = 1, \dots, n$? Maybe there are conditions under which relationship $*$:$\mathrm{E}(Y_i - Y_j) \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{E}_{ij}(Y) \geq 0$ -- takes place?

I can't get my head around how to approach this. All I know is that if all of the $Y_i$'s are mutually independent, this, indeed, results in $*$: when $y_i = y_j$, the numerator is zero, so this case adds nothing to $\mathrm{E}_{i,j}(Y)$; else we know that $y_i+y_j=1$ in denominator, so we end up with nominator and denominator not having any dependent variables. However, as far as I can see, this approach does not work even if $Y_i, Y_j$ are pairwise independent for all $i \ne j$.

Comment: Isn't it possible for the denominator to be 0?

Comment: @MichaelChernick It sure is, so we assume that in this case the whole fraction is equal to zero.

Comment: I suspect there isn't much that can be said in general.  After all, the ways in which the $Y_k$ depend on $(Y_i,Y_j)$ for $k\ne i,j$ can even change the sign of the expectation.  A better way to get some help with this question would be to explain where it comes from and/or to describe the joint distribution in greater detail.